# Firebase Query in React - I Can Log to Console, But Cannot Use in Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to see in this component users with their photos.

I can see id's of each user, so `database.getUserList` function works! But there is something wrong with `getAdditionalUserInfoById` function.

```js
import { database } from "../firebase";

class UsersInfo extends Component {
  render() {
    let users = database.getUserList(this.props.id);

    return (
      <div>
        <List>
          {Object.keys(users).map(key => (
            <ListItem>
              <Avatar>
                <ImageAvatars
                  photoUrl={database.getAdditionalUserInfoById(
                    users[key]["userId"],
                    "photoUrl"
                  )}
                />
              </Avatar>
              <ListItemText
                primary={users[key]["userId"]}
                secondary="Jan 9, 2014"
              />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have `getAdditionalUserInfoById` in another file that queries firebase. With this `console.log` command, I can see the correct `photoUrl` value of each user in console, but in the component above it is `undefined`. How can I get it to `UsersInfo` component, what should be fixed here?

```js
export const getAdditionalUserInfoById = (userId, query) => {
  var userDbRef = database.ref("users/" + userId);

  userDbRef
    .child("additionalInfo")
    .child(query)
    .on("value", function(snapshot) {
      console.log("userInfoById: ", snapshot.val());
      return snapshot.val();
    });
};
```

Firebase DB Structure:

```
"users" : {
  "h06c4wAxn0eeN3yQ4Qw9DfEVww03" : {
     "additionalInfo" : {
        "photoUrl" : "https://thumb.ibb.co/iVW1y9/Screen_Shot_2018_05_10_at_12_23_59_PM.jpg"
     }
   }
 }
```

***** UPDATE *****

```js
class InfoWindowContent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      userPhotos: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ users: database.showUserListbyGeoId(this.props.id) });
    var userPhotos = [];
    Object.keys(this.state.users).map(function(key) {
      userPhotos[
        this.state.users[key]["userId"]
      ] = database.getAdditionalUserInfoById(
        this.state.users[key]["userId"],
        "photoUrl"
      );
    });
    this.setState({ userPhotos });
  }

  render() {
    const { users, userPhotos } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <List>
          {Object.keys(users).map(key => (
            <ListItem>
              <Avatar>
                <ImageAvatars
                  photoUrl={this.state.userPhotos[users[key]["userId"]]}
                />
              </Avatar>
              <ListItemText
                primary={users[key]["userId"]}
                secondary={"31 Dec, 2035"}
              />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My Firebase Database Functions

```js
// ../firebase.js
export const showUserListbyGeoId = cityId => {
  var userList = [];
  var cityUserListRef = database.ref("cities/" + cityId + "/users");
  cityUserListRef.orderByChild("userId").on("value", function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var key = childSnapshot.key;
        userList[key] = childSnapshot.val();
      });
    }
  });
  return userList;
};

export const getAdditionalUserInfoById = (userId, query, callback) => {
  var userDbRef = database.ref("users/" + userId);
  userDbRef
    .child("additionalInfo")
    .child(query)
    .on("value", snapshot => {
      return callback(snapshot.val());
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`database.getUserList` is async function. You must wait for data returning.
The solution is, define a state in component. After the data returned, you would `setState`, and the view would be updated.

I don't know about your `database.getUserList` use callback or `Promise`. If it return the `Promise`, the example like this:

```js
class UsersInfo extends Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { users: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    database.getUserList(this.props.id)
      .then((results) => {
        this.setState({ users: results });
      });
  }


  public render() {

    const users = this.state.users;
    ...
  }
}
```

For `getAdditionalUserInfoById`, because it is event listener, you can use callback

```
export const getAdditionalUserInfoById = (userId, query, callback) => {
      var userDbRef = database.ref('users/' + userId);
      userDbRef.child("additionalInfo").child(query).on("value", (snapshot) => {
        callback(snapshot.val());
      });
    })
}
```

```js
componentDidMount() {
    const self = this;
    getAdditionalUserInfoById(userId, query, (value) => {

      // set state or do something
      self.setState({ user: value })
    })

  }
```

UPDATE:

```js
// ../firebase.js
export const showUserListbyGeoId = (cityId, callback) => {
  const userList = [];
  const cityUserListRef = database.ref("cities/" + cityId + "/users");

  cityUserListRef.orderByChild("userId").on("value", (snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        userList.push(childSnapshot.val());
      });  
    }

    return callback(userList);
  });
};

export const getAdditionalUserInfoById = (userId, query) => {
  var userDbRef = database.ref("users/" + userId);
  return userDbRef
    .child("additionalInfo")
    .child(query)
    .once("value")
    .then((snapshot) => ({
      [query]: snapshot.val(),
      userId,
    }));
};
```

```js
class InfoWindowContent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      userPhotos: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const self = this;

    database.showUserListbyGeoId(this.props.id, (userList) => {
      self.setState(userList);

      return Promise.all(
        userList.map(({ userId }) => database.getAdditionalUserInfoById(
          userId,
          "photoUrl"
        ))
      ).then((userPhotos) => {
        self.setState({ userPhotos })
      });
    });

  }

  render() {
    const { users, userPhotos } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <List>
          {userPhotos.map((photo) => (
            <ListItem>
              <Avatar>
                <ImageAvatars
                  photoUrl={photo.photoUrl}
                />
              </Avatar>
              <ListItemText
                primary={photo.userId}
                secondary={"31 Dec, 2035"}
              />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What about getAdditionalUserInfoById? How should I use it in componentDidMount?

Comment: I update `getAdditionalUserInfoById` sample. You can use callback to do it

Comment: I've tried to grab them on state, but not worked for me. I've updated description above, and I will be very pleased if you could look into?

Comment: `showUserListbyGeoId` is same as `getAdditionalUserInfoById`. You must setState inside callback function

Comment: I still couldn't do it but thank you for your time anyway. If you have time, would you share full code?

Comment: I update new code. I think you should learn more about basic of JavaScript. You misuse array as object. Array can not be set as key, value

Comment: When I run your code above, I get an erroy saying: **TypeError: callback is not a function**. That is for: `return callback(userList);` in showUserListbyGeoId function. Thank you for your advise btw, I will do that

Comment: Any ideas @hgiasac ? I guess we're so close to the final!

Comment: I can not debug your code. I don't sure about which reason. Did you debug to determine what callback's type is? I think it is because of wrong parameter input